# How to make Apple's "Hide My Email" into its own stand alone application?

Tags: html, swift, macos, icloud, macos-monterey

I've been beating my head against my desk for hours, and I can't seem to figure out how to call the "Hide My Email" window outside of safari.

When you select an email address field as in the image below

[image]

you are able to call the "Hide My Email" window.

[image]

Using the `Accessibility Inspector` showed that it is an HTML type application, and you can inspect it like you would any other web page.

Does anyone have any idea on how to call this outside of Safari?

Answer (score 0):

Apple said this feature is available only in Safari, so I guess it is not available for us mortals, just like some other cool stuff like system toasts in iOS.